# Installed Module: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pycharm, importerror

Like the title states: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame' error.

Pygame is installed but PyCharm says it's not (when compiling). It's installed in ..\venv\Lib\site-packages.

I've reinstalled Pygame in both cmd and pygame terminal. Also both with the virtual environment activated and without it.

I've read 15+ posts about this error and none of the fixes work. Does anyone know a fix that could work?

Comment: Is pygame listed at File - Settings - Project - Python Interpreter?

Answer (score -1):

PyCharm itself needs virtual environments to be defined in the Project Interpreter settings. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-interpreter.html

Comment: Care to elaborate on this answer with some more details rather than just a link? [answer] indicates "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline"